# Slim Framework 3 401 response can't set WWW-Authenticate header

Tags: rest, slim, slim-3

Have a REST application using Slim Framework v3.  All works as expected, but I cannot seem to set headers for the response.

For example:

```
$app->any('/[{path:.*}]', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = null ) use ( $objError, $objDBCon, $objUtil ) {
...
return $response->withAddedHeader( 'WWW-Authenticate', 'API-key realm="restricted"' )
                ->withJson($apiResults, $httpcode);
});
```

Works as expected in terms of getting data, getting the correct http status code, etc.

For example I get a the correct response JSON

```
{ "message": "You must be logged in to access this resource" }
```

and I get the expected status code:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

and all the standard, correct headers, content-type, etc, etc.

But cannot seem to set any additional headers.

Reference documentaiton https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html

Comment: Try to add headers after you call `withJson`, like `withJson()->withAddedHeader()` to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reputation is to low to add a comment:

According to the manual

> withAddedHeader method appends the new value to the set of values that already exist for the same header name

Does your header already exists before appending?

I usually create a new header for each response, something like this:

```
return $response = $next($request, $response)
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $this->allowedhosts)
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->withStatus(200);
```

hope this helps.